# cakePHP : Warning (2): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 4 to be boolean

Tags: date, cakephp, date-format, htmlspecialchars, validation

I want to display the date as DMY: example 07-07-1975

But with this code:

```
<?php echo h($player['Player']['player_birthDate'], array('dateFormat'=>'DMY')); ?>
```

I get the error message:

```
Warning (2): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 4 to be boolean, array given [CORE\Cake\basics.php, line 198]

htmlspecialchars - [internal], line ??
h - CORE\Cake\basics.php, line 198
include - APP\View\Players\index.ctp, line 34
View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 935
View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 897
View::render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 466
Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 952
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 192
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 160
require - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108
[main] - ROOT\index.php, line 41
```

Model:

```
'player_birthDate' => array(
   'date' => array(
       'rule' => array('date'),
   ),
),
```

Comment: That's the expected behavior, nothing to be surprised of **[API Reference > h()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/function-h.html)** Have you checked the docs for a solution? **[Cookbook > TimeHelper::format()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::format)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest way to use PHP date function like

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($player['Player']['player_birthDate'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Time` [helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::format) class to format the date and time   : -

load Time helper in controller

```
public $helpers = array('Time');
```

print formatted date in the view

```
echo h($this->Time->format('2011-08-22 11:53:00','%A-%B-%Y'));
```

output : -
  Monday-August-2011